# C# image concatenation

Tags: c#

What i want to is, take 3 images, that the 1st image, keep it to original size concatenate anothother image to the bottom of it only using 1/2 of the first images size( starting on the left side).  Then take the 3rd image and put it on the bottom right half of the first image  I've looked for example all day, does anybody have an idea or an idea?

Comment: Do you need to maintain the aspect ratio of the second and third image?

Comment: I would perfer to keep the aspect ratio of all 3 images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ignore aspect ratio:

```
        Image img1;
        Image img2;
        Image img3;

        Bitmap display = new Bitmap(img1.Width, (int)(img1.Height * 1.5));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(display);

        //draw img1 to upper left corner
        g.DrawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        //draw img2 under img1, left side
        g.DrawImage(img2, 0, img1.Height, img1.Width / 2.0f, img1.Height / 2.0f);

        //draw img3 under img1, right side
        g.DrawImage(img3, img1.Width / 2.0f, img1.Height, img1.Width / 2.0f, img1.Height / 2.0f);
```

Comment: this works great, just wish it didnt ignore aspec ration heh.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm not understanding the question right, but it seems like you could just create a new `Bitmap` and draw the 3 images into it at the right coordinates, which you should be able to figure out from the individual image dimensions (which I believe the `Bitmap` object gives you)

Comment: maybe, i've been doing bit of looking into and it really wasnt looking all that great.