# how do i merge multiple images into a single image ?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have an array of Images all of the same size . I should add them to a new image like i have shown in the picture.

Different colors represent different images.
[image]

Comment: And by "add" do you mean to add (combine) pixel-wise or do you mean you want to create a larger image that contains all other images in a row or grid?

Comment: I want to create an larger image[should be a size of A4 size paper] and store all these small images like i have shown in the picture

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075032/c-sharp-image-concatenation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints

Answer (score 4):

1. Identify the size of final image
2. Create a bitmap with final height and width `var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);`
3. Draw each image on canvas

   ```
   using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
   {
       canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
       //Draw each image (maybe use a loop to loop over images to draw)
           canvas.DrawImage(someImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(0, 0, Frame.Width, Frame.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

       canvas.Save();
   }
   ```
4. Save the final image `bitmap.Save("image path", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`