# Adding two image into one image c#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I want to combine two image but I cant success . Help me please.

When try the combine `PictureBox` show only first image but there is not second image , when I remove first image I can see second image.

Also I tried setting first image and draw the text on image that's also not working. Please help.

```
Image myimg = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(textBox1.Text, 2, true);

Bitmap image = new Bitmap(myimg.Width + 20, myimg.Height + 50);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, myimg.Width + 20, myimg.Height + 50));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myimg.Width + 20, myimg.Height);
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(myimg.Width + 20, 20);
Graphics Cizgi2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
Graphics Cizgi = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
Cizgi.DrawImage(myimg, 0, 0);

FontStyle sitil = FontStyle.Bold;
Font fonts = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 10, sitil);
Cizgi2.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fonts, Brushes.Black, 5, myimg.Height + 10);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(10, 0));
g.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(0, bmp.Height + 10));
```

---

[I want to image seems like first  but  i cant make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0bWN.jpg)

Comment: You want to show both images side-by-side or you want to add one image over the top of the other?

Comment: Please define how you want to combine the images. Side by side, under/over or overlaid in some way?

Comment: You really should explain better what you want to do and answer the question we ask !! Combining two images is simple, 4-5 lines of code and diplaying the result takes one more line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to concatenate two images vertically?  It's pretty simple actually, you can look here ([C# image concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075032/c-sharp-image-concatenation)), but I've also modified it for your needs.  I think this should work:

```
        float drawBorderX = 5;
        float drawBorderY = 5;

        //Set up our two images
        Bitmap barCode = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(textBox1.Text, 2, true);
        Bitmap text = new Bitmap(barCode.Width, 50);
        Graphics textGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(text);


        //Draw the text to the bottom image.
        FontStyle sitil = FontStyle.Bold;
        Font fonts = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 10, sitil);
        textGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(0, 0, text.Width, text.Height));
        textGraphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fonts, Brushes.Black, drawBorderX, drawBorderY);

        //Vertically concatenate the two images.
        Bitmap resultImage = new Bitmap(Math.Max(barCode.Width, text.Width), barCode.Height + text.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage);
        g.DrawImage(barCode, 0, 0);
        g.DrawImage(text, 0, barCode.Height);
```

Edit:  Note that resultImage will contain the image you want, so you can set your PictureBox to be that image at the end.

Comment: its works . i just add  Bitmap barCode = (Bitmap) Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(textBox1.Text, 2, true);